# DialogFragment.show() throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I'm making my first major Android app, and I'm trying to show a dialog in an `ActionBarActivity`. I've created a subclass of DialogFragment:

```
public class QuestionFragment extends DialogFragment {
private final String[] CHOICES = {"More than once per day","Once per day","Less often"};

public QuestionFragment() {
    //Required empty constructor
}

public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("How often do you take this medication?")
            .setItems(CHOICES, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //options for int which go here
                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}
}
```

I try to use the show method in a very similar way to how the Android developer tutorials explain it. The dialog is supposed to come up when a button is clicked:

```
public void toAdd(View view) {
    QuestionFragment dialog = new QuestionFragment();
    dialog.show(dialog.getFragmentManager(),"question");
}
```

When I try this, I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.FragmentTransaction android.app.FragmentManager.beginTransaction()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:228)
        at gianttine.rescription.TodayMeds.toAdd(TodayMeds.java:49)
        ...
```

I've also tried changing `(dialog.getFragmentManager(),"question");` to `(getFragmentManager(),"question");`, and I've also tried making a `FragmentManager` object before passing it into `show()`.

As I'm new to Android development, I may have some poor design choices in that code, but I am looking to find out why there is an exception and what I need to do to make the dialog show properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `dialog.getFragmentManager()` when your dialog isn't even attached to an Activity and therefore CAN'T have access to a `FragmentManager`. That's only possible after it gets attached.

What you need to do is get a valid `FragmentManager`, i.e. from the component, that invokes your `toAdd()` method.

So:

```
public void toAdd(View view) {
    QuestionFragment dialog = new QuestionFragment();
    dialog.show(getFragmentManager() /*<--- depends where it's invoked, inside an Activity it's the right way, inside another Fragment, it would be getChildFragmentManager*/,"question");
}
```